Ошибка LNK 2001. Неразрешенный тип файла
Уже какой час бьюсь и понять не могу почему не отображаются данные.
File 1.cpp:
double factorised= 4.1;
int str = 31;
extern void update();
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Ru");    
    
    cout << &factorised <<endl;
    update();
    
    
    

}

File2.cpp:
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
extern double factorised;
extern int str;
using namespace std;
void update();
void update()
{
    cout << factorised << endl;
    cout << str << endl;
}

Ошибки:
Ошибка
LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "void __cdecl update(void)"
(?update@@YAXXZ) в функции main.    Pratha_2    D:\C++Projects\Pratha_2\Pratha_2.obj
            
Ошибка  
LNK2001 неразрешенный внешний символ "double factorised" (?factorised@@3NA)
.   DevelopGamesFromBook    D:\C++Projects\DevelopGamesFromBook\FileName.obj    1       


По сообщения судя, компилируете файлы по отдельности...
